# Silk Browser's full screen option has gone on Kindle Fire HDX?

Tags: stock-browser, amazon-kindle

Am I going nuts (well, yes, but ..), or has Amazon Kindle Fire HDX removed full screen from the silk browser? I can not find the full screen button now, just a sort of menu button in the navigation bar right hand side.

Comment: Not sure if [Amazon's Silk Browser manual](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201730570) is updated or not...

Answer (score 2):

Nope. Not nuts. Yup. They rolled out a version without full screen for some reason.

From an e-mail inquiry:

> Note: As part of this redesign, we have temporarily removed the Full Screen feature. We plan to bring this feature back in the coming months and apologize for any inconvenience.